# amzon redshift ERROR: Intermediate result row exceeds database block size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

when we run a query that has some 100 columns,we got the error :  ,it exceeds the database block size.please show me some solutions. our cluster is 4 nodes with dw2.large machines.

Comment: What percent of free space is on your cluster according to the web console? Very large queries could use 20% or more disk space during intermediary processing. Could you provide the query?

Comment: Also if you have a 100 column table, you may be doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i am  running with a lot of VARCHAR (MAX) columns,so that i faced the issue.i resolved my issue by tight the Varchar limit as much as possible. if you find any solution please post.

Comment: I am facing the same issue , could you please suggest what all steps you have taken to tight the varchar limit.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, since redshift doesn't support pivots, had to use a lot of CASE WHEN to make about 100 columns with varchar datatype, faced first issues recently, quick fix is to add ::varchar(1000) or instead of 1000 - max number of letters which might appear in that column. Solved the problem for me.

Also - this solution is just a quick fix, to do that better - consider using some sort of ETL, maybe pandas to do the pivoting or initial manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/9eu5js/aws_redhsift_error_intermediate_result_row/) this error often occurs when dealing with columns that contain long strings or that contain the result of string manipulation.
In this case, after manipulating the string, what worked for me is to specify the maximum number of characters that the field can contain. For example:

```
SELECT (...)
,MAX(CASE
    WHEN split_part(var1,'->', 2) = '' THEN NULL
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN (var2 LIKE 'pattern1%') THEN CONCAT('aaaa->', var1)
            WHEN (var2 LIKE 'pattern2%') THEN CONCAT('cccc->', var1) 
            ELSE split_part(var1,'->', 2) 
        END
END)::varchar(20) AS result_variable
FROM (...)
```

In this case the maximum number of characters my variable can contain is 20